# WebView2 print to pdf

Tags: webview2

I use WebView2 to visualization Power BI embedded report in # net desktop application. The report is visualized correct in application but when I try to print as pdf the generated file don't have any content(just blank document).

```
var printSettings = webView.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreatePrintSettings();
  printSettings.ScaleFactor = 1;
  printSettings.Orientation = Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2PrintOrientation.Landscape;
  printSettings.ShouldPrintBackgrounds = true;
                
  await webView.CoreWebView2.PrintToPdfAsync(dl1.FileName, printSettings);
```

Comment: You mean the output PDF is just a blank document?

Comment: Out of interest, are you running your application with elevation? There is known issue that causes this behaviour. Try without elevation.